# Zend Framework 2 and mysql using ssh

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2, database-connection, mariadb

I am trying to log into a remote machine which has a MariaDB database hosted on it through my Zend Framework 2 application. I am just trying to wrap my head around how to log into the system and then connect to the MariDB. This is how my global.php looks like,and i have the database user name and password defined in the local.php

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=DB;host=username@127.0.0.1',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
            => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Unable to get through this.

Answer (score 0):

You need a SSH tunnel up and running between the two hosts and then route your mysql/mariadb connection over the tunnel. A good, relevant example can be found here: http://quintagroup.com/services/support/tutorials/mysql-linux

Please note that you'll experience a performance penalty due to encrypting/decrypting through the SSH tunnel and network latency between the ZF2 app server and database server. For development purposes should be fine, though...